# Unable to detect locks in sqlite

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am using SQLite in python through the Python sqlite3 module. I am multiprocessing on a shared database but not multithreading.

Reading the documentation for [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) it appears that one should control locking through Connection.isolation_level().

However when I open two different python interactive processes and perform the statements (below) I get the same result. Both processes apparently have the database locked exclusively.

What sequence of Python statements would lead to one process having the lock and the other process knowing that it had been denied? How would the locked-out process learn that it was locked out? Would sqlite3 raise an error or is there an error return from Connection.isolation_level()?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Mar 31 2017, 11:27:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('data/precinctTracker.db')
>>> conn
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x1011a53d0>
>>> conn.isolation_level ='EXCLUSIVE'
>>> conn.isolation_level 
'EXCLUSIVE'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `isolation_level` property controls the [transaction behaviour](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), which does not really have much of an effect in your application.

A connection will take a lock only when it actually accesses the database file. So to test locking, you have to execute some SQL command to read or write something.

If a connection cannot acquire a lock, you get a "database is locked" error.
Most transactions are short (if you didn't forget to call `commit()`), so you can prevent this by setting a [busy timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout).